# mysql stored procedure error in creation

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am new in learning stored procedure.Now I am trying to make a procedure which will generate a random number and store it in a variable and then insert the value in another table.

```
create procedure getRand() 
begin 
delcare rc varchar(255); 
SELECT CHAR(ROUND(65 + FLOOR( RAND() * 57 ))) into rc; 
insert into Rand_loader (snum,rnum) values (rc,rc);
end//
```

But when I tried to run this on mysql then it gives this error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rc varchar(255); 
SELECT CHAR(ROUND(65 + FLOOR( RAND() * 57 ))) into rc; 
insert' at line 3
```

I am unable to understand this error.Ill appreciate your help
Please help me to solve this

Comment: DECLARE you have a typo

Comment: problem solved by the suggestion given in comment.Yes it is the DECLARE issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace `declare` with `DECLARE` and always try to use capital letters while writing SQL commands.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code. It works for me

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    PROCEDURE `yourdatabasename`.`getRand`()
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
    BEGIN
 DECLARE rc VARCHAR(255); 
SELECT CHAR(ROUND(65 + FLOOR( RAND() * 57 ))) INTO rc; 
INSERT INTO Rand_loader (snum,rnum) VALUES (rc,rc);

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can download `SQLyog` from here

```
https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list
```

to create tables and stored procedure with visual tools

Answer (score 1):

You have written "declare" wrong.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getRand`()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
declare rc varchar(255); 
SELECT CHAR(ROUND(65 + FLOOR( RAND() * 57 ))) into rc; 
insert into Rand_loader (snum,rnum) values (rc,rc);
END
```